# Hierarchical model in Tensorflow probability using JointDistributionSequential

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm trying to understand how to implement the following model in Tensorflow probability.

1. An angle, `theta`, has uniform prior probability in the range `[-pi / 2, +pi / 2]`;
2. A direction-flip probability, `beta`, has uniform prior probability in range `[0, 1]`;
3. `theta'` is set to either:

   - `theta' = theta + pi` with probability `beta`; or
   - `theta' = theta` with probability `(1 - beta)`;
4. Concentration `c` has a HalfCauchy prior probability; and
5. An observation, `alpha` is drawn from the [von Mises distribution](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/VonMises), centred on `theta'` with concentration `c`.

So far what I've tried is

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
tfd = tfp.distributions

model = tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
    [
        tfd.Uniform(-np.pi / 2, +np.pi / 2, name='theta'), # theta
        tfd.Uniform(0.0, 1.0, name='beta'), # beta
        tfd.HalfCauchy(loc=0, scale=1), # c
        lambda c, beta, theta: tfd.VonMises(
            loc=theta + np.pi * tfd.Binomial(probs=beta),
            concentration=c,
            name='observed'
        ), # Observation, alpha
    ]
)
```

Calling this gives an error on the binomial part: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'total_count'`.  What am I doing wrong?

### Updated 2020-03-17

Latest code is as follows. I'm still trying to find out how to implement part (3) of my model, i.e. flip the direction of my angle, `theta`, by adding `pi` with probability `beta`.  Any help on this would be appreciated! What I have so far doesn't work because I can't multiply the Bernoulli object by a float.

```
model = tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
    [
        tfd.Uniform(-np.pi / 2, +np.pi / 2, name='theta'), # theta
        tfd.Uniform(0.0, 1.0, name='beta'), # beta
        tfd.HalfCauchy(loc=0, scale=1), # c
        lambda c, beta, theta: tfd.VonMises(
            loc=theta + np.pi * tfd.Bernoulli(probs=beta, dtype=tf.float32),
            concentration=c,
            name='observed'
        ), # Observation, alpha
    ]
)
```

Comment: I think you might want to use `MixtureSameFamily`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of multiplying a number by a distribution in the `loc` parameter calculation can be fixed by sampling from the Bernoulli distribution i.e.

```
...
loc=theta + np.pi*tfd.Bernoulli(probs=beta, dtype=tf.float32).sample(),
...
```

This allows sampling from the joint distribution but I'm not sure that it's correct.

Another approach is to pull out the `flip` random variable and scale using a bijector i.e.

```
tpb = tfp.bijectors
model = tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
[
    tfd.Uniform(-np.pi / 2, +np.pi / 2, name='theta'), # theta
    tfd.Uniform(0.0, 1.0, name='beta'), # beta
    lambda beta, theta: tfb.Scale(np.pi)(tfd.Bernoulli(probs=beta, dtype=tf.float32)), #flip
    tfd.HalfCauchy(loc=0, scale=1), # c
    lambda c, flip, beta, theta: tfd.VonMises(
        loc=theta + flip ,
        concentration=c,
        name='observed'
    ), # Observation, alpha
]
```

)

This also allows sampling from the joint dictribution and has the advantage of being able to see when flips happen.

Comment: I think the second approach is probably better, though now note you have a discrete value, which will make sampling hard. You could try RelaxedBernoulli to get a continuous 0-1 value with concentrations around 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Swap out Bernoulli for Binomial. Binomial is the sum of a `total_count` number of bernoulli draws.

Comment: BTW if you are using `tfp-nightly` I'd suggest looking at some of the `JointDistribution*AutoBatched` classes. Docs here https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions?version=nightly.

Comment: Thanks - understand I need to use Bernoulli instead of Binomial.  How do I implement step (3) in my model (setting theta' to theta + pi depending on the Bernoulli draw). What I've done isn't right because it raises `unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Bernoulli'`

Comment: Pass dtype=tf.float32 to the constructor. https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Bernoulli

Comment: Sorry I still don't quite understand. I'm now using `theta + np.pi * tfd.Bernoulli(probs=beta, dtype=tf.float32)` to set the `loc` of the VonMises, but still get the same error.

Comment: [See Matt McDonnell's answer.]